# Mixed date format in data frame column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, format, timezone

I have a dataframe with mixed date formats across and within columns. When trying to convert them from object to datetime type, I get an error due to column date1 having a mixed format. I can't see how to fix it in this case. Also, how could I remove the seconds from both columns (date1 and date2)?

Here's the code I attempted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[10, "2021-06-13 12:08:52.311 UTC", "2021-03-29 12:44:33.468"], 
                            [36, "2019-12-07 12:18:02 UTC", "2011-10-15 10:14:32.118"]
                           ]),
                   columns=['col1', 'date1', 'date2'])
df

>>
   col1 date1                        date2
0   10  2021-06-13 12:08:52.311 UTC  2021-03-29 12:44:33.468
1   36  2019-12-07 12:18:02 UTC      2011-10-15 10:14:32.118


# Converting from object to datetime
df["date1"]= pd.to_datetime(df["date1"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f UTC")
df["date2"]= pd.to_datetime(df["date2"], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

>>
ValueError: time data '2019-12-07 12:18:02 UTC' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f UTC' (match)
```

Comment: `df["date1"]= pd.to_datetime(df["date1"].str.strip('UTC'), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", utc = True)` ?? OR `df["date1"]= pd.to_datetime(df["date1"], infer_datetime_format =True)`

Comment: That worked but ended up placing the same value of .%f than the line before. That's why I keep wondering if simply removing the seconds for both columns would be more convenient. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for conversion to datetime, i found the infer_datetime_format to be helpful.
could not get it to work on the complete dataframe, it is able to convert one column at a time.

```py
In [19]: pd.to_datetime(df["date1"], infer_datetime_format=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[19]: 
0   2021-06-13 12:08:52.311000+00:00
1          2019-12-07 12:18:02+00:00
Name: date1, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

In [20]: pd.to_datetime(df["date2"], infer_datetime_format=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[20]: 
0   2021-03-29 12:44:33.468
1   2011-10-15 10:14:32.118
Name: date2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If atleast all formats start with this format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" , then you can just slice all strings till that point and use them

```py
In [32]: df['date1'].str.slice(stop=16)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[32]: 
0    2021-06-13 12:08
1    2019-12-07 12:18
Name: date1, dtype: object
```

for getting rid of the seconds in your datetime values, instead of simply getting rid of those values, you can use [round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) , you can also check floor and ceil whatever suits your use case better.

```py
In [28]: pd.to_datetime(df["date1"], infer_datetime_format=True).dt.round('T')                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[28]: 
0   2021-06-13 12:09:00+00:00
1   2019-12-07 12:18:00+00:00
Name: date1, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]

In [29]: pd.to_datetime(df["date2"], infer_datetime_format=True).dt.round('T')                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[29]: 
0   2021-03-29 12:45:00
1   2011-10-15 10:15:00
Name: date2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: `df.set_index('col1').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, infer_datetime_format= True).dt.round('T'))` this will work on complete `df` : )

Comment: I need both to have the exact same format... when doing the rounding as you can see you get 00+00:00 for date1 and 00 for date2... I'm looking for a way of they both to look the same or simply dissapear completely...

Comment: Nevermind! with the code above if you set utc = False it and then round the seconds it works. Thank you!